# Trying to exit Ruby processes

Tags: ruby

When I attempt to exit ruby processes, namely, specs, rails console, and `binding.pry` calls, there are two options: ctrl+c, ctrl+z, or if things are really stuck, open a separate tab and `killall ruby`. However, when I ctrl+c the first time, the terminal outputs `Exiting... Interrupt again to exit immediately.` but hangs permanently. If I ctrl+c again to force exit, it successfully exits. However, from that point on, I can no longer see what I'm typing into the shell. So if I type `ls`, the line will still appear blank, but if I hit enter, it will successfully execute the `ls` command.

When I ctrl+z, it manages to stop the process successfully. However, after doing this a few times, I wind up with a bunch of ruby processes running, which seem to block running new ruby processes. In this scenario, `killall ruby` does nothing (nor does any derivative such as looking up by `pid`). I have to open activity monitor (mac) and force quit each proc individually.

Any ideas how I managed to get myself into this/how to resolve it?

Comment: One word for you: `SIGKILL`. As in `killall -m ruby -9`. I do it all the time with `spring`. That thing just won't exit gracefully.

Comment: As to why it happens on your machine, I have no idea. Something must be different. Compare the specs/configs of the two machines.

Comment: killing a suspended process does not work, unless you kill it with SIGKILL.

Comment: There's a GitHub issue: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1183

Comment: @Sergio, I am reminded of a [brief, but famous, conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dug-G9xVdVs&feature=youtu.be) between Benjamin and one of his elders in the movie *The Graduate*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing *all* your Ruby instances is a shotgun approach; you might hit targets you didn't intend, so I suggest to avoid it.

When your shell doesn't show what you're typing any more you need to (blindly) enter `reset` to reset the terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't kill your process, it just get's suspended. You should get an output that tells you a job number, like:

```
[1]  + 95295 suspended  man reset
```

Here, 1 is the job number. You can then resume the command by typing `fg %<jobnumber>`, in this example `fg %1`. Or you can kill it with `kill -9 %<jobnumber>`, like `kill -9 %1`.

Comment: awesome, no more constantly re-cding into the same directory, thanks!

Comment: Or just `fg` to resume the current job